# "Cannot create direct3d device for tcustomcanvasd2d"

Tags: delphi, windows-vista, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm getting the above error with FireMonkey projects in Delphi XE7 under Windows Vista.

The error occurs

- When creating a new project.
- When trying to view an FMX form for projects which work fine in XE6.
- At run time for above mentioned XE6 projects when compiled by XE7.

The run time issue appears to be happening when loading the FMX form.

I note that Vista is no longer officially supported by XE7 either at design time or run time:  http://www.embarcadero.co.uk/products/delphi/datasheet

Is there any known work around to get XE7 FireMonkey and Vista 64 to work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct2D is only supported in "[Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Platform Update for Windows Vista and later](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370990(v=vs.85).aspx)".